# Hide Text that is scrolled behind input in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my example i have a fixed input `data-spy="affix"` that is shifted downwards by `90px` because of the parent `<div class="container" style="margin-top:80px">`.

So the only thing that should scroll is the text. This actually works!

My problem is that the text that is scrolled behind the input is visible and i would like to hide it!

[image]

I tried to add a white box before the input but all my tries where not really successful!
So i hope you can help me! Thanks

http://bootply.com/113734

Comment: It will be the best to make the parent of your input position fixed. Give this element a background-color, like white. Position the element at the very top of the text container. a more portable solution would be to make the Text-container scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

in fact @nico-o already gives the answer here. Wrap your input inside a div and apply the affix on this:

```
<div style="background-color:white;padding-top:80px;" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1">
<input class="form-control" id="searchterm" name="tags" placeholder="Input" type="text">  
</div>
```

Doing this you will have the same kind of problem as described here: [Bootstrap 3RC1 + Side Panel + Affix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114351/bootstrap-3rc1-side-panel-affix/18966454).

To solve this add:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('.affix').width($('.container').width());
});
```

See: http://bootply.com/113811

@nico-o also suggest a scrollable Text-container, see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-examples for an example